# Best way to select date from a calendar and display it in the TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-calendar

I have searched a lot and need to know the best way possible to select a date from a calendar, I am already trying a fragment such as

FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

DialogFragment fragment=new DatePickerDialogFragment(MainActivity.this);
fragment.show(transaction, "date_dialog");

but have errors regarding imports , as they are conflicting i believe...
really need a way out, does anyone have a good solution , please do let me know i need it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to do this with Dialog.
First of all, set `android:focusable="false"` on your `EditText` in your xml.

Then you can try something like this:

```
yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextID);
        yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // To show current date in the datepicker
                Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(yourActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedyear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedmonth);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedday);
                        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //Change as you need
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.FRANCE);
                        yourEditText.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

                        mDay = selectedday;
                        mMonth = selectedmonth;
                        mYear = selectedyear;
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                //mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
```

Where mYear,mMonth and mDay are global int.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
DatePicker mDlgDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    mEdtxDate.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1 < 10 ? "0" : "") + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-"
                            + (dayOfMonth < 10 ? "0" : "") + dayOfMonth);
                }
  }, 2014, 1, 1);
  mDlgDatePicker.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN DATE PICKER WITH SELECTED DATE AS DEFAULT DATE**

1. Initially add this code as a global scope, somewhere above or outside of onCreate()

   ```
    //this will show default date as current date initially
    private val currentDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    private var year = currentDate[Calendar.YEAR]
    private var month = currentDate[Calendar.MONTH]
    private var day = currentDate[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
   ```
2. on your TextView, add this OnClickListener:

   ```
    binding.tvDate.setOnClickListener {
        selectDate()
    }
   ```
3. Here is your selectDate() Function:

   ```
    private fun selectDate() {
    val mDatePicker = DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        { _, selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay ->
            val myFormat = AppConstants.DateFormat.DF_dd_MM_yy
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            day = selectedDay
            month = selectedMonth
            year = selectedYear
            currentDate.set(year, month, day)
            binding.tvDate.text = sdf.format(currentDate.time)
        }, year, month, day
    )

    mDatePicker.show()
    mDatePicker.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple))

    mDatePicker.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple))
   ```

   }

Here. `DF_dd_MM_yyyy` is `const val DF_dd_MM_yyyy = "dd/MM/yyyy"`